# how to display only one item in bootstrap date paginator

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this below source code, which is giving me [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oNBe.png) output

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mobile Page</title>
    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DmABxgPhJN5jlTwituIyzIUk6oqyzf3+XuP7q3VfcWA2unxgim7OSSZKKf0KSsnh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="paginator"></div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepaginator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#paginator').datepaginator();
        });
    </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

but I want to display like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOMcq.png) How can I achieve this, PLease help me, THANKS IN advance.

Comment: What have you tried? - Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Comment: @ochi I have published the code which I have already tried. I have also mentioned what output I'm getting, and what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The `paginator` plugin seems to be outdated and it does not seem to have the option to display/hide the additional days.

However, you could add your own CSS to hide the elements you do not want to show, like this:

```
#paginator .dp-item{
   display: none;
}

#paginator .dp-selected{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

One more thing, depending on the version of JQuery, Paginator Plugin, Bootstrap and Moment, you may get a warning about the plugin using deprecated functions (as I did) - This is the best combo I could come up with given my limited time today.

**See the demo below:**

```js
$(function() {
  // options for paginator
  var options = {
    textSelected: 'MMMM DD, YYYY'
  }

  $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
});
```

```css
#paginator .dp-item {
  display: none;
}

#paginator .dp-selected {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepaginator/1.1.0/bootstrap-datepaginator.js"></script>

<!-- stylesheets -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DmABxgPhJN5jlTwituIyzIUk6oqyzf3+XuP7q3VfcWA2unxgim7OSSZKKf0KSsnh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepaginator/1.1.0/bootstrap-datepaginator.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div id="paginator" class="col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @JamieSouthwell if you find an answer helpful, you can upvote it. If you find the correct answer to your question, you can mark it as such.